# Recursive Ray Traversal Algorithm - Traverse k-d Tree

Tags: tree, traversal, line-intersection

I have chosen a stack based traversal algorithm (*Recursive Ray Traversal Algorithm*), and I am having a little trouble understanding it.

Here is what I understand.

I need to find a point where the ray enters the *voxel* (then calculate the distance ray origin and that point) where it exits (then calculate the distance between ray origin and that point), distance between *ray origin* and *plane* (in some papers I saw the formula:

```
(splitPoint - rayOrigin[currentAxle]) / rayOrientation[currentAxle]
```

My ray orientation is `(0, 0, -1)` and then in some cases I will be dividing with zero (because `x = 0` and `y = 0`). How can this be?

And in the init of the algorithm, the ray origin is in the main voxel, how do I get the distance where the ray enters the voxel?

Do I understand this correctly? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

**It's from the book "Physically Based Rendering From Theory to Implementation".**

[image] 
Two cases where both children of a node don’t need to be processed because the ray
doesn’t overlap them.

(a) The top ray intersects the splitting plane beyond the ray’s **t_max** position and thus doesn’t enter the far child. The bottom ray is facing away from the splitting plane, indicated by a negative **t_split** value.

(b) The ray intersects the plane before the ray’s **t_min** value, indicating that the near child doesn’t need processing.